# Add new blog post using Blogger API

Tags: vb.net, post, google-api, blogger

I want to add post on my blog using vb.net with [Blogger's API v3](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using).

I've generated OAuth client ID and secret from URL above, but I'm not sure where to use it.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/8070105920543249955/posts/
Authorization: /* OAuth 2.0 token here */
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "kind": "blogger#post",
  "blog": {
    "id": "8070105920543249955"
  },
  "title": "A new post",
  "content": "With <b>exciting</b> content..."
}
```

Above is how POST request for adding new blog post should look.

I cannot find OAuth 2.0 token anywhere which has to be put in header on second line. I've tried adding oauth **client_id:client_secret** (my own) and also encoding it in Base64, but I'm still getting unauthorized response.

Comment: You need an access token.  To get that you need to request user consent.  This link might help https://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/

Answer (score 0):

I am not knowing anything about VB.net but still, the thing you ask for is from where do you get an OAuth token.
You can get it from [OAuthPlayground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) website by Google.